# Python scipy.ndimage.morphology.dilation

Tags: png, scipy, morphing

I have a huge problem concerning png images.
My png is a black/white letter (The letter is white, the background is black).
No colors between them.
My problem is, I want/must use in some way binary_dilation/erosion...
But when I try to do this, I get an image which is white inside and the background is blue??

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave

template = imread("temp.png")/255.0
imsave("Result.png",binary_dilation(template))
```

I have absolutely no clue why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of the color channels --- if "temp.png" has it, then `template.shape == (nx, ny, 3)` or with alpha `template.shape == (nx, ny, 4)`. Binary dilation treats the last dimension as the third spatial dimension, rather than as a color channel, which is not what you usually want. You can do `binary_dilation(template[:,:,0])` to enforce a 2-D image operation.

Comment: Thanks :)
Hint helped just fine!